# Mobile filtered list or a data view table

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a data extension which get refreshed by an external system and a mobile filtered list that has opted in and opted out customers on device level. I need to run an sql wo find the matches and I'm not sure whether using a mobile filtered list the right thing to do. Should I run it from a data view table instead? If yes, would it be _PushAddress, it has no subscriber key to match with. Or do I create a mobile filtered list with 2 filters in the list: opted in - Yes(2) and Opted in - No (1)?